# CheckBox in RecyclerView keeps on checking different items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Here's the XML for my items inside the RecyclerView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cvItems"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="0dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:id="@+id/tvContent"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" />
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbSelect"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:button="@drawable/cb_checked"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And here's the RecyclerView adapter that inflate the layout above for each of its items:

```
public class AdapterTrashIncome extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterTrashIncome.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ObjectIncome> myItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public AdapterTrashIncome(ArrayList<ObjectIncome> getItems, Context context){
        try {
            mContext = context;
            myItems = getItems;
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(FILE_NAME, "51: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvContent;
        public CheckBox cbSelect;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            tvContent = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
            cbSelect = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cbSelect);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ObjectIncome objIncome = myItems.get(position);
        String content = "<b>lalalla</b>";
        holder.tvContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(content));
    }
}
```

The problem is, let's say I have 10 items inside the RecyclerView. When I checked the checkbox on item 1,2,3 then I scroll down the RecyclerView, suddenly some of the other items eg items 8,9 is checked. And when I scroll up again, item 1 and 3 is checked but not item 2. Any idea why this happen?

Comment: Try to use [this library](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter), see ViewStates. It helps to save a state when scroll.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

That's an expected behavior. You are not setting your checkbox selected or not. You are selecting one and View holder keeps it selected. You can add a boolean variable into your ObjectIncome object and keep your item's selection status.

You may look at my example. You can do something like that:

```
public class AdapterTrashIncome extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterTrashIncome.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ObjectIncome> myItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public AdapterTrashIncome(ArrayList<ObjectIncome> getItems, Context context){
        try {
            mContext = context;
            myItems = getItems;
            }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(FILE_NAME, "51: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvContent;
        public CheckBox cbSelect;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            tvContent = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
            cbSelect = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cbSelect);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ObjectIncome objIncome = myItems.get(position);
        String content = "<b>lalalla</b>";
        holder.tvContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(content));

        //in some cases, it will prevent unwanted situations
        holder.cbSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        //if true, your checkbox will be selected, else unselected
        holder.cbSelect.setChecked(objIncome.isSelected());

        holder.cbSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    //set your object's last status
                    objIncome.setSelected(isChecked);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I totally forgot I had this exact problem few months ago and have written a solution like you suggested. Thanks anyway

Comment: It didn't work. You have to write `holder.cbSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);` before `holder.cbSelect.setChecked(objIncome.isSelected()) `

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov Yes, in some cases, you may need it. I will edit my answer.

Comment: is there any reason as to why setting holder.cbSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null); works?

Comment: if (isButtonChecked) {
                        getItem(position).setIsSelected(true);
                    } else if (getItem(position).isSelected()) {
                        compoundButton.isChecked();
                    } else {
                        compoundButton.setChecked(false);
                    }               This if else condition has avoided duplicate checks when onBindViewHolder replaces the view.

Comment: @oguzhand hi I tried your solution but its not working either way: with or without setting listener to null.

Comment: @Abbas I used this method many times and working definately. Also working for other 23 people(at least) too. Maybe your case is a little different than this one. Or may be something is wrong in your adapter. Use debugging.

Comment: @oguzhand Thanks for the reply. I only posted my question _after_ I had debugged my code and so far (after an hour's work) nothing at all. Check state is perfectly stored in the adapter's list. And provides the correct check state in `onBindView()` however I am still getting unwanted checked CheckBoxes.

Comment: @Abbas you should check and uncheck your checkbox each time onBindView() called. In my answer, checkbox checked/unchecked according to object you set. Check your objects' states.

Comment: @oguzhand Here's the code from `onBindViewHolder`.
`@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemHolder holder, int position) {
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.checkBox.setSelected(list.get(position).isSelected());
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setSelected(isChecked);
            }
        });`

Comment: Why this doesn't work instead holding the checkbox status in `final ObjectIncome objIncome = myItems.get(position);` holding the checkbox status in the `ViewHolder holder` ?

Comment: @Suisse you need to keep checkbox status in an object, because ViewHolder is just a holder. If you have 100 items, you have only about 6-7(depends on screen and layout size) ViewHolders and use these all objects in a cycle.

Comment: setOnCheckedChangeListener(null) resolve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: you dont have to call setOnCheckedChangeListener(null). just check if the button is pressed . like this:  cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {
                      if (compoundButton.isPressed())
                    { //do your work here}}

Comment: You need to write if else condition to show check boxes correctly.

Comment: @Oğuzhan Döngül Tnx you saved my time. +1 vote for u.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, it saved much of my time!

Comment: the holder.cbSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null); fix my issue thank good lord!

Comment: setOnCheckedChangeListener(null) resolved my problem, it's makes sence, recycler view does not destroy items, so when the bind method is called, it has already an onChangeListener associated with old data, and as you set isChecked manually, that fires a change event, and the old listener is called. Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 27):

In short, its because of recycling the views and using them again!

how can you avoid that :

1.In `onBindViewHolder` check whether you should check or uncheck boxes.
don't forget to put both if and else

```
if (...)
    holder.cbSelect.setChecked(true);
else
    holder.cbSelect.setChecked(false);
```

2. Put a listener for check box! whenever its checked statues changed, update the corresponding object too in your `myItems` array ! so whenever a new view is shown, it read the newest statue of the object.

Comment: Your second point was the key. Although it works best in a situation, when the initial dataset also has information about checked state (which is the case for me)

Comment: this is the more straight-to-the-point and correct answer. SetCheck for BOTH true and false in onBindViewHolder is the key

Comment: In my case, I have to save the data in the data model with default value `isChecked` `false` for all the data set on start, then `onCheckChanged` I just updated the `isChecked` value to `true` or `false` and as told in the answer implement that check either checked or not.

Answer (score 24):

Just add two override methods of `RecyclerView`

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Don't do that!! It will bypass the recyclerView recycling mechanism and lose the whole point of using it.

Comment: No it won't, it just returns the exact position of every recycled view in the view holder.

Comment: Harish, maybe i'm missing something, but as far as I know, by doing this you actually tell the adapter that the number of items types is the items count. The meaning is that no item can be recycled because it has no simillar view. It is easy to test though. just log the viewHolder.itemView referrence inside onBindViewHolder and see if there are two viewHolders holding the same view referrence. The test should be on a long list so the recycling system will be executed.

Comment: It woked flawlessly, It saved my day.

Comment: in case you have more then 100 items in your recyclerview, this solution will load all items at once, this might cause OutOfMemoryException in case you have images means otherwise this solution is perfect @Kundan

Answer (score 19):

**Use this only if you have limited number of items in your RecyclerView.**

I tried using `boolean` value in model and keep the `CheckBox` status, but it did not help in my case. What worked for me is `this.setIsRecyclable(false);`

```
public class ComponentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ...
        this.setIsRecyclable(false);
    }
```

More explanation on this can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#isRecyclable())

**NOTE:** This is a workaround. To use it properly you can refer the document which states

> Calls to setIsRecyclable() should always be paired (one call to setIsRecyclabe(false) should always be matched with a later call to setIsRecyclable(true)). Pairs of calls may be nested, as the state is internally reference-counted.

I don't know how to do this in code, if someone can provide more code on this.

Comment: please can you explain how to use it ?

Comment: isn't it waste of the logic behind recyclerView?

Comment: I tried this with long list which solved the random checking issue but when I scroll down and re-scroll up with long list, the checked checkboxes disappear :(

Comment: It's not a good idea to make view unrecyclable as it will drain memory and you'll lose most of benefits of recycler view.

Comment: I agree with you guys, @eren130 and Arthur. I have edited the post, and would very much appreciate if we can come up with a way to use setIsRecyclable(true / false); properly.

Comment: this will load all items in a recyclerview at once, if recyclerview has 200 items means OutOfMemoryException will come.

Comment: is 80 items will make out of memory exception?  i will use this as temporary solution.. #beginnerproblem

Comment: It's good to downvote this answer because it wastes logic behind recycler view.

Answer (score 14):

You can use **Model** class to keep track of each `RecyclerView` item's `CheckBox`. Full reference is from : ***[RecyclerView Checkbox Android](http://demonuts.com/2017/07/03/recyclerview-checkbox-android/)***

`setTag` and `getTag` is used to keep track of `CheckBox` status. Check full reference link for more information. It also teaches how to send checked items to ***Next Activity***.

Make `Model` class:

```
public class Model {
 
    private boolean isSelected;
    private String animal;
 
    public String getAnimal() {
        return animal;
    }
 
    public void setAnimal(String animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
    }
 
    public boolean getSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }
 
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }
}
```

Create `integer.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="btnplusview">1</integer>
    <integer name="btnpluspos">2</integer>
</resources>
```

Finally `RecyclerView.Adapter` looks like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public static ArrayList<Model> imageModelArrayList;
    private Context ctx;

    public CustomAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Model> imageModelArrayList) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        this.imageModelArrayList = imageModelArrayList;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.checkBox.setText("Checkbox " + position);
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(imageModelArrayList.get(position).getSelected());
        holder.tvAnimal.setText(imageModelArrayList.get(position).getAnimal());

        // holder.checkBox.setTag(R.integer.btnplusview, convertView);
        holder.checkBox.setTag(position);
        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Integer pos = (Integer) holder.checkBox.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(ctx, imageModelArrayList.get(pos).getAnimal() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (imageModelArrayList.get(pos).getSelected()) {
                    imageModelArrayList.get(pos).setSelected(false);
                } else {
                    imageModelArrayList.get(pos).setSelected(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imageModelArrayList.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected CheckBox checkBox;
        private TextView tvAnimal;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb);
            tvAnimal = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.animal);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Using Kotlin the only thing which solved this problem for me was to clear the `OnCheckedChangeListener` before setting the variable and then create a new `OnCheckedChangeListener` after `checked` has been set.

I do the following in my `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`

```
task.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
task.isChecked = item.status
task.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _: CompoundButton, checked: Boolean ->
    item.status = checked
    ...
    do more stuff
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is perfectly working. I don't why but this only works when anyone using KOTLIN!

Comment: That's really working. What he has done is very clever and obvious at the same time.
`task.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)` just considered the checkbox as a brand new one as we are just interested in new events only. Again very clever.

Answer (score 5):

It might be very late but the simplest of all answers is to assign the check state in bind `ViewHolder`. `RecyclerView` will check and apply that state when reusing.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder, position: Int) {
    binding.checkbox.isChecked = item.isChecked
}
```

Maintain that state in your class. (Assign a initial default value)

```
class MyItem {
    val isChecked: Boolean = false
}
```

`onClickListener` do your stuff and assign the state to class variable. In my case, I have delegate `clickListener` in view. So, it is like this in `Adapter`:

```
binding.checkbox.setOnClickListener {
    onClickListener.invoke(item) 
}
```

Then, in view, I am doing this:

```
val adapter = MyItem { item->
    viewModel.checkedContactsList.value?.let { list ->
        if (list.contains(item)) {
            item.isChecked = false
            list.remove(item)
        } else {
            item.isChecked = true
            list.add(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend that not to use `checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener` in `RecyclerView.Adapter`. Because on scrolling `RecyclerView`, `checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener` will be fired by adapter. **It's not safe**. Instead, use `checkBox.setOnClickListener` to interact with user inputs.

For example:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

     ...
        
     holder.checkBoxAdapterTasks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             boolean isChecked = holder.checkBoxAdapterTasks.isChecked();
             if (isChecked) {
                 // checkBox clicked and checked
             } else {
                 // checkBox clicked and unchecked
             }
         }
     });   
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case this worked.

```
@Override
public void onViewRecycled(MyViewHolder holder) {
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(false); // - this line do the trick
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
}
```

Comment: For some reason, this solution works perfect !

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate `onBindViewHolder(logic)` interactions with `CheckBox` and user interactions with checkBox. I used `OnCheckedChangeListener` for user interactions (obviously) and `ViewHolder.bind()` for logic, that's why you need to set checked listener to null before setting up holder and after holder is ready - configure checked listener for user interactions.

```
boolean[] checkedStatus = new boolean[numberOfRows];

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ViewHolderItem itemHolder = (ViewHolderItem) holder;

    // holder.bind should not trigger onCheckedChanged, it should just update UI
    itemHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    itemHolder.bind(position);

    itemHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                checkedStatus[holder.getAdapterPosition()] = true;
                performCheckedActions(); //your logic here
            } else {
                checkedStatus[holder.getAdapterPosition()] = false;
                performUncheckedActions(); //your logic here
            }
        }
    });
}

public void bind(int position) {
    boolean checked = checkedStatus[position];
    if (checked) {
        checkBox.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated above, the checked state of the object should be included within object properties. In some cases you may need also to change the object selection state by clicking on the object itself and let the CheckBox inform about the actual state (either selected or unselected). The checkbox will then use the state of the object at the actual position of the given adapter which is (by default/in most cases) the position of the element in the list.

Check the snippet below, it may be useful.

```html
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class TakePicImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TakePicImageAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private Context context;
    private List<Image> imageList;

    public TakePicImageAdapter(Context context, List<Image> imageList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageList = imageList;
    }

    @Override
    public TakePicImageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.image_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final TakePicImageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        File file=new File(imageList.get(position).getPath());
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file));
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        holder.selectImage.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.selectImage.setChecked(imageList.get(position).isSelected());
        holder.selectImage.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                holder.selectImage.setChecked(isChecked);
                imageList.get(position).setSelected(isChecked);
            }
        });
        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (imageList.get(position).isSelected())
                {
                    imageList.get(position).setSelected(false);
                    holder.selectImage.setChecked(false);
                }else
                {
                    imageList.get(position).setSelected(true);
                    holder.selectImage.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imageList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView image;public CheckBox selectImage;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            selectImage=(CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ch);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will happened when use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` instead of that use `setObClickListener` and inside that just do this easy handle:

```
if (list.get(position).isCheck()) {
    list.get(position).setCheck(false);
} else {
    list.get(position).setCheck(true);
}
```

Note: in your list model add one boolean variable with name `check` and set getter and setter for that , in above case mine is setCheck and isCheck

Answer (score 2):

**Use an array to hold the state of the items**

In the adapter use a `Map` or a [SparseBooleanArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html) (which is similar to a `Map`, but is a key-value pair of `int` and `boolean`) to store the state of all the items in our list of items and then use the keys and values to compare when toggling the checked state.

In the `Adapter` create a `SparseBooleanArray`:

```
// sparse boolean array for checking the state of the items
private SparseBooleanArray itemStateArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
```

Then in the item click handler `onClick()` use the state of the items in the `itemStateArray` to check before toggling, here is an example

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
    if (!itemStateArray.get(adapterPosition, false)) {
        mCheckedTextView.setChecked(true);
        itemStateArray.put(adapterPosition, true);
    } else {
        mCheckedTextView.setChecked(false);
        itemStateArray.put(adapterPosition, false);
    }
}
```

Also, use sparse boolean array to set the checked state when the view is bound:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (items == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return items.size();
}

void loadItems(List<Model> tournaments) {
    this.items = tournaments;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    CheckedTextView mCheckedTextView;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mCheckedTextView = (CheckedTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checked_text_view);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // use the sparse boolean array to check
    void bind(int position) {
        if (!itemStateArray.get(position, false)) {
            mCheckedTextView.setChecked(false);}
        else {
            mCheckedTextView.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
}
```

and final adapter will be like [**this**](https://gist.github.com/e4basil/a9027ccc400486ef45879dd96e5cadad).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in a `RecyclerView` list with switches, and solved it using **@oguzhand** answer, but with this code inside the `checkedChangeListener`:

```
if (buttonView.isPressed()) {
    if (isChecked) {
        group.setSelected(true);
    } else {
        group.setSelected(false);
    }
} else {
    if (isChecked) {
        buttonView.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        buttonView.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Where 'group' is the entity I want to select/deselect.

Comment: You may optimize your code by replacing inner **if-else** statement: `group.setSelected(isChecked);`, `buttonView.setChecked(!isChecked);`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by creating a static global array and using it in `onBindViewHolder`

###### RecyclerView.Adapter realization class:

In which I created all global variables/objects needed.

```java
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {
    
    private Context context;

    ...

    public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cv;
        TextView question, category;
        TextView personAge;
        ImageView upvote;
        Button b1;
        public static int k;
        private int visibleThreshold = 5;
        public static int i = 0;
        static int check[]; //Static array

        PersonViewHolder(View itemView, int i) {
            super(itemView);

            if(i == PersonViewHolder.k) {
                b1 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.loadmore);
            } else {
                cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
                question = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.question);
                category = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_categ);
                personAge = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                upvote = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.upvote);
            }
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Here (*in contructor of `RVAdapter` class*) I gave size to the array equals to the size of items I'm going to display in the `RecyclerView`:

```
List<Person> persons;

RVAdapter(List<Person> persons){
    this.persons = persons;
    PersonViewHolder.check = new int[persons.size()];
    PersonViewHolder.k = persons.size();
}
```

In `onBindViewHolder` I applied this concept on a button. When I click on a button - the background image of the button changes.

Object of button I used is names as "upvote", as "i" holds the position of each item in `RecyclerView`. I used it as an index of array which is working as a flag and which is keeping track of status of elements.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, final int i) {
    if (i == PersonViewHolder.k) {
        personViewHolder.b1.setText("load more");
    } else {
        personViewHolder.question.setText(persons.get(i).name);
        personViewHolder.personAge.setText(persons.get(i).age);

        if (personViewHolder.check[i] == 0) {
            personViewHolder.upvote.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.noupvote);
        } else {
            personViewHolder.upvote.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.upvote);
        }

        personViewHolder.upvote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (personViewHolder.check[i] == 0) {
                    personViewHolder.check[i] = 1;
                    personViewHolder.upvote.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.upvote);
                } else {
                    personViewHolder.check[i] = 0;
                    personViewHolder.upvote.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.noupvote);
                }
            }
        });

        // personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(persons.get(i).photoId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. When I was clicking on item's - toggle buttons become checked in my `RecyclerView`. Toggle buttons appeared in every 10th item (for example if it was clicked in item with 0 index, items with 9, 18, 27 indexes were getting clicked too).

My code in `onBindViewHolder` was:

```
if (newsItems.get(position).getBookmark() == 1) {
    holder.getToggleButtonBookmark().setChecked(true);
}
```

But then I added `else` statement:

```
/**
 * Else statement prevents auto toggling.
 */
if (newsItems.get(position).getBookmark() == 1) {
    holder.getToggleButtonBookmark().setChecked(true);
} else{
    holder.getToggleButtonBookmark().setChecked(false);
}
```

And the problem was solved!

Comment: Thank you. Else part will clear the checkbox if it check by default when recycling view the same view.

Answer (score 1):

Okay there is a lot of answers **here**. But I will post my code and I will simply explain what I did... it maybe help juniors like me :D.

##### Objective:

We will create a `list` of `RecyclerView` that has `CheckBox` and `RadioButton`, something like this:

[image: list items with check boxes and radio buttons]

##### Model for list item with all needed data:

```java
public class ModelClass {

    private String time;
    private boolean checked;
    private boolean free;
    private boolean paid;

    public TherapistScheduleModel(String time, boolean checked, boolean free, boolean paid) {
        this.time = time;
        this.checked = checked;
        this.free = free;
        this.paid = paid;
    }

    public boolean isFree() {
        return free;
    }

    public void setFree(boolean free) {
        this.free = free;
    }

    public boolean isPaid() {
        return paid;
    }

    public void setPaid(boolean paid) {
        this.paid = paid;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public boolean getChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked= checked;
    }
}
```

##### My `RecyclerView.Adapter` amazing realization:

```java
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ListAllListeners listAllListeners;
    private ArrayList<ModelClass> mDataList;

    public MyAdapter(
        Context context, 
        ArrayList<ModelClass> mDataList,
        ListAllListeners listAllListeners
    ) {
        this.mDataList = mDataList;
        this.listAllListeners = listAllListeners;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_view, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mDataList != null) {
            return mDataList.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // important to:
        // setOnCheckedChangeListener to 'null'
        holder.checkBoxTime.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.freeRB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.paidRB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        // Check Box
        holder.checkBoxTime.setText(mDataList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getTime());
        // Here we check if the item is checked or not from the model.
        if(mDataList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getChecked()) {
            holder.checkBoxTime.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            holder.checkBoxTime.setChecked(false);
        }

        holder.checkBoxTime.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b) {
                    mDataList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setChecked(true);
                    listAllListeners.onItemCheck(holder.checkBoxTime.getText().toString(), holder.getAdapterPosition());
                } else {
                    mDataList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setChecked(false);
                    listAllListeners.onItemUncheck(holder.checkBoxTime.getText().toString(), holder.getAdapterPosition());
                }
            }
        });

        // Radio Buttons

        if(mDataList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).isFree()) {
            holder.freeRB.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            holder.freeRB.setChecked(false);
        }

        holder.freeRB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b) {
                    mDataList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setFree(true);
                    listAllListeners.onFreeCheck(holder.freeRB.getText().toString(), holder.getAdapterPosition());
                } else {
                    mDataList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setFree(false);
                    listAllListeners.onFreeUncheck(holder.freeRB.getText().toString(), holder.getAdapterPosition());
                }
            }
        });

       // And so on to paidRB

    }

    /**
     * Here is a list of clicked listeners to use them as you want ;).
     * You can get a list of checked or unchecked of all.
     */
    public interface ListAllListeners {
        void onItemCheck(String checkBoxName, int position);
        void onItemUncheck(String checkBoxName, int position);
        void onFreeCheck(String name, int pos);
        void onFreeUncheck(String name, int pos);
        void onPaidCheck(String name, int pos);
        void onPaidUncheck(String name, int pos);
    }
    
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    
        CheckBox checkBoxTime;
        RadioButton freeRB, paidRB;
    
        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            checkBoxTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeCheckBox);
            freeRB = itemView.findViewById(R.id.freeRadioBtn);
            paidRB = itemView.findViewById(R.id.paidRadioBtn);
        }
    }
}
```

##### In `Activity` you get them something like this:

```
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, mDataList, new MyAdapter.ListAllListeners() {

    @Override
    public void onItemCheck(String checkBoxName, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + checkBoxName + "  " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemUncheck(String checkBoxName, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + checkBoxName + "  " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFreeCheck(String name, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + name + "  " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFreeUncheck(String name, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + name + "  " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaidCheck(String name, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + name + "  " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaidUncheck(String name, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + name + "  " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a Kotlin Solution That Worked for Me

```
class SpecialtyFragmentRecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<SpecialtyFragmentRecyclerAdapter.SpecialtyViewHolder>(){

    private var _specialtySet = mutableSetOf(
        "Yoruba Attires",
        "Hausa Attires",
        "Senator",
        "Embroidery",
        "Africa Fashion",
        "School Uniform",
        "Military and Para-Military Uniforms",
        "Igbo Attires",
        "South-South Attires",
        "Kaftans",
        "Contemporary",
        "Western Fashion",
        "Caps"
    ).toSortedSet()

    val specialtySet: Set<String> get() = _specialtySet
    val savedSpecialtySet = mutableSetOf<String>().toSortedSet()

    inner class SpecialtyViewHolder(
        var itemBinding: SpecialtyFragmentRecyclerItemBinding
    ) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root) {

        fun bind(specialty: String) = with(itemBinding) {

            specialtyFragmentYorubaAttiresCheckBox.text = specialty
            specialtyFragmentYorubaAttiresCheckBox.isChecked = savedSpecialtySet.contains(specialty)

     //AREA OF INTEREST

     //Either Setting the CheckBox onCheckChangeListener to works
     specialtyFragmentYorubaAttiresCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)

     specialtyFragmentYorubaAttiresCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
                CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                    if (buttonView.isPressed) { //OR this Also Works {Check if the Button is Pressed Before verifying the Checked State}
                        if (isChecked) {
                            savedSpecialtySet.add(specialty) //Perform Your Operation for Checked State
                        } else {
                            savedSpecialtySet.remove(specialty) //Perform Your Operation for unChecked State
                        }
                    }
                }
            )

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SpecialtyViewHolder {
        val viewBinding = SpecialtyFragmentRecyclerItemBinding
            .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return SpecialtyViewHolder(viewBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SpecialtyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val specialty = _specialtySet.elementAt(position)
        holder.bind(specialty)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return _specialtySet.size
    }

    fun populateList(list: MutableList<String>) {
        savedSpecialtySet.addAll(list)
        _specialtySet.addAll(list)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun addNewSpecialty(specialty: String) {
        _specialtySet.add(specialty.trim())
        savedSpecialtySet.add(specialty.trim())
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun removeSpecialty(element: String) {
        _specialtySet.remove(element)
        savedSpecialtySet.remove(element)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TagYourDiseaseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TagYourDiseaseAdapter.OrderHistoryViewHolder> {

    private ReCyclerViewItemClickListener mRecyclerViewItemClickListener;
    private Context mContext;

    List<Datum> deviceList = Collections.emptyList();

    /**
     * Initialize the values
     *
     * @param context : context reference
     * @param devices : data
     */
    public TagYourDiseaseAdapter(Context context, List<Datum> devices,
                                 ReCyclerViewItemClickListener mreCyclerViewItemClickListener) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.deviceList = devices;
        this.mRecyclerViewItemClickListener = mreCyclerViewItemClickListener;
    }

    /**
     * @param parent   : parent ViewPgroup
     * @param viewType : viewType
     * @return ViewHolder
     * <p>
     * Inflate the Views
     * Create the each views and Hold for Reuse
     */
    @Override
    public TagYourDiseaseAdapter.OrderHistoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_tag_disease, parent, false);
        TagYourDiseaseAdapter.OrderHistoryViewHolder myViewHolder = new TagYourDiseaseAdapter.OrderHistoryViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    /**
     * @param holder   : view Holder
     * @param position : position of each Row set the values to the views
     */
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final TagYourDiseaseAdapter.OrderHistoryViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(deviceList.get(position).getIconUrl()).into(holder.document);
        holder.name.setText(deviceList.get(position).getDiseaseName());

        holder.radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.radioButton.setChecked(deviceList.get(position).isChecked());

        //if true, your checkbox will be selected, else unselected
        //holder.radioButton.setChecked(objIncome.isSelected());

        holder.radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                deviceList.get(position).setChecked(isChecked);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return deviceList.size();
    }

    /**
     * Create The view First Time and hold for reuse
     * View Holder for Create and Hold the view for ReUse the views instead of create again
     * Initialize the views
     */
    public class OrderHistoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        ImageView document;
        TextView name;
        CheckBox radioButton;

        public OrderHistoryViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            document = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_tag);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_tag_name);
            radioButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rdBtn_tag_disease);
            radioButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            //this.setIsRecyclable(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           mRecyclerViewItemClickListener.onItemClickListener(this.getAdapterPosition(), view);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is due to again and again creating view ,best option is clear cache before setting adapter

```
recyclerview.setItemViewCacheSize(your array.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Complete example:**

```
public class ChildAddressAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChildAddressAdapter.CartViewHolder> {

    private Activity context;
    private List<AddressDetail> addressDetailList;
    private int selectedPosition = -1;

    public ChildAddressAdapter(Activity context, List<AddressDetail> addressDetailList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.addressDetailList = addressDetailList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.address_layout, parent, false);
        return new CartViewHolder(myView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.adress_checkbox.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            selectedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        });

        if (selectedPosition==position){
            holder.adress_checkbox.setChecked(true);
        }
        else {
            holder.adress_checkbox.setChecked(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  addressDetailList.size();
    }

    class CartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView address_text,address_tag;
        CheckBox adress_checkbox;

        CartViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            address_text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.address_text);
            address_tag = itemView.findViewById(R.id.address_tag);
            adress_checkbox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adress_checkbox);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is while `CheckBox` is checked. Need to store this separate list, and use that list to populate `CheckBox` in `RecyclerView`.

You can refer this [link](https://blog.oziomaogbe.com/2017/10/18/android-handling-checkbox-state-in-recycler-views.html).

Answer (score 0):

If it is not late; this is actually `RecyclerView` general problem. You can put your `RecyclerView` into a `NestedScrollView` and then add one line code to your adapter. All is done.

In your activity or fragment;

```xml
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And in your activity where you set adapter add this:

```java
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView, false);

LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
// your adapter code...
recyclerView.setAdapter(textSearchAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onBindViewHolder` for views (checkbox, radio, switch, ...) you should `setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)` before and after new creation. For example:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder,
                             int position) {
    ...
    holder.switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    ...
    holder.switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton,
                                     boolean b) {
            // TODO: 10/23/2022 do something
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue while using checkbox inside recycler view. After some detail analysis I got the root cause. let's look at the code once

In onBindViewHolder the line "holder.cbSelect.setChecked(yourList.isSelected());"
will always execute.

If we scroll up or scroll down the page, the onBindViewHolder will get called. As soon as onBindViewHolder will get called "holder.cbSelect.setChecked(yourList.isSelected());" will get tiggered and as a result
"holder.cbSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener" will also get called and it will change the checkbox state, even if you have not changed the checkbox state. The reason is simple that it found checkbox state is changed from your updated list (yourList.isSelected()) which you select or dis-select the check box .

Now as a solution in override method of "public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)" method we need to add one condition that is

```
holder.cbSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                     if (buttonView.isPressed()) {
       
    
     //Check box state changed by user
                    //update your list based on checkbox value
                    // yourList.setSelected(isChecked);
                        
                       }
                   
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me is to nullify the listeners on the viewHolder when the view is going to be recycled (`onViewRecycled`):

```
 override fun onViewRecycled(holder: AttendeeViewHolder) {
            super.onViewRecycled(holder)
            holder.itemView.hasArrived.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            holder.itemView.edit.setOnClickListener { null }
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Adding `setItemViewCacheSize(int size)` to `RecyclerView` and passing size of list solved my problem.

###### My code:

```
mrecyclerview.setItemViewCacheSize(mOrderList.size());
mBinding.mrecyclerview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Source: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46951440/10459907)