# Get list of checked checkboxes from recyclerview android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I have populated the recyclerView with image, title and checkbox.
I have two problems.

1. How to make the checkbox selected when the imageview or the whole recycler item is clicked.
2. I have to go to next activity by getting all the checked items from the recyclerview.

My layout :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="Interests"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_yash_dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="GYM"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final InterestBean model = arrayList.get(position);
    final int pos = position;

    RecyclerViewHolder mainHolder = (RecyclerViewHolder) holder;// holder

    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
    model.getImage());// This will convert drawbale image into bitmap

    // setting title
    mainHolder.title.setText(model.getTitle());
    mainHolder.imageview.setImageBitmap(image);
    mainHolder.checkBox.setChecked(arrayList.get(position).isSelected());
    mainHolder.checkBox.setTag(arrayList.get(position));

    mainHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            InterestBean contact = (InterestBean) cb.getTag();

            contact.setIsSelected(cb.isChecked());
            arrayList.get(pos).setIsSelected(cb.isChecked());
            selectedItems.add(pos);
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), pos + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

One simple solution is to create `OnItemCheckLister`, and implement it similar to following:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerViewAdapter {

    interface OnItemCheckListener {
        void onItemCheck(Item item);
        void onItemUncheck(Item item);
    }

    ...

    @NonNull
    private OnItemCheckListener onItemClick;

    public MyAdapter (List<Item> items, @NonNull OnItemCheckListener onItemCheckListener) {
        this.items = items;
        this.onItemClick = onItemCheckListener;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof MyViewHolder) {
            final Item currentItem = items.get(position);

            ...
     
            ((MyViewHolder) holder).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((MyViewHolder) holder).checkbox.setChecked(
                            !((MyViewHolder) holder).checkbox.isChecked());
                    if (((MyViewHolder) holder).checkbox.isChecked()) {
                        onItemClick.onItemCheck(currentItem);
                    } else {
                        onItemClick.onItemUncheck(currentItem);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CheckBox checkbox;
        View itemView;

        ...

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.itemView = itemView;
            checkbox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            checkbox.setClickable(false);
            ...
        }

        public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the activity, we can do this:

```
    private List<Item> currentSelectedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    
    ...

    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(items, new MyAdapter.OnItemCheckListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemCheck(Item item) {
                currentSelectedItems.add(item);
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemUncheck(Item item) {
                currentSelectedItems.remove(item);
            }
        });
```

Then you can do stuff with `currentSelectedItems`.

Note: Since this solution suppose for the whole Item to be pressed so the checkbox is set to be not clickable.

Comment: That's simply amazing, people please use this solution!

Comment: its Fab to use :)

Comment: Hey @ninjahoahong I'm getting an error on "onItemClick.onItemUncheck(currentItem);" this line. My error is: Attempt to invoke interface method on a null object reference. Please help!!

Comment: @akshayashok how did you initialize your `items` and `adapters`?

Comment: This solution is a very good start.  I noticed that when my recycler got long, weird behavior started to happen.  Instead of using the view holder to check if the item is selected,  it is better to keep that state as part of your `List<item>` that way,  the `is.checked()` is preserved when the recycler starts to reuse the viewholder.  Here is a good example that helped fix this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32428115/8890753

Answer (score 5):

You can use Model class to get recyclerView checked items. More reference : **[Android Recyclerview checkbox](http://demonuts.com/2017/07/03/recyclerview-checkbox-android/)**

Model

```
public class Model {

    private boolean isSelected;
    private String animal;

    public String getAnimal() {
        return animal;
    }

    public void setAnimal(String animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
    }

    public boolean getSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
 import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.CheckBox;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import java.util.ArrayList;


  public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
public static ArrayList<Model> imageModelArrayList;
private Context ctx;

public CustomAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Model> imageModelArrayList) {

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    this.imageModelArrayList = imageModelArrayList;
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.checkBox.setText("Checkbox " + position);
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(imageModelArrayList.get(position).getSelected());
    holder.tvAnimal.setText(imageModelArrayList.get(position).getAnimal());

   // holder.checkBox.setTag(R.integer.btnplusview, convertView);
    holder.checkBox.setTag(position);
    holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Integer pos = (Integer) holder.checkBox.getTag();
            Toast.makeText(ctx, imageModelArrayList.get(pos).getAnimal() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (imageModelArrayList.get(pos).getSelected()) {
                imageModelArrayList.get(pos).setSelected(false);
            } else {
                imageModelArrayList.get(pos).setSelected(true);
            }
        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return imageModelArrayList.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected CheckBox checkBox;
    private TextView tvAnimal;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb);
        tvAnimal = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.animal);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you use your Model objects in more than one different recyclerviews with different sort order or different purpose of check state you have to add a different boolean for each. It's less effort to save a list with id or key and the state for each purpose.

Comment: Can we  do it without the use of isSelected as i am using a contact object for Realm

Answer (score 3):

first set a boolean value in moodel class

and clicking of checkbox pass boolean true

and checked all check box is clicked or not by following method

```
 fun isListContainMethod(arraylist: List<Puzzle>): Boolean {
    for (puzzle in arraylist) {
        if (!puzzle.isSelect) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can add mainHolder.imageview OnClickListener
2)  Two step:

1. Add to InterestBean model boolen isChecked
2. Where go to next activity, get all InterestBeans, get all checked      InterestBeans and save it.

Code:

```
mainHolder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick (View v)
    {
        mainHolder.checkBox.setChecked(!mainHolder.checkBox.isChecked());
    }
});
```

Comment: How to set the checkBox checked on image click listener.

Comment: mainHolder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // How to set it cheked?
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

from [@ninjahoahong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36597344/7891465) 
I add checkbox listenner in onBindViewHolder method and checkbox can click able.

```
viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int pos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        ChoiceItem currentItem = mChoice.get(pos);
        if(viewHolder.checkBox.isChecked()){
            onItemCheckListener.onItemCheck(currentItem);
            currentItem.setCheck(true);
        }else{
            onItemCheckListener.onItemUncheck(currentItem);
            currentItem.setCheck(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, int position) {
        List list= aList.get(position);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), movie.getTitle() + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        action(list.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

    }
}));
```

Comment: please add some brief that what you did special.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me and will work for you as well
Just Create Static List, I created it on MainActivity.java

```
public static List<String> myItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

Create setOnCheckedChangeListener in YouAdapter.class

```
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(b){
                myItems.add(Model.getYouItem());
            }
            else{
                myItems.remove(Model.getYouItem());
            }
        }
    });
```

Now you can use your myItems list to perform operations.