# Using same adapter for multiple similar reyclerview implementation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i make an adapter intended to show date and checkbox like image below

[image: see it here]

it works fine, just like what i want
but i got to a problem using same adapter in multiple dialog that i wanna show that have the same behavior

i expect the checkbox in my second recyclerview not checked because i havent check the checkbox on my second recyclerview

the data/ checked checkbox saved on first dialog is showing on my second adapter and so on
i have try to using different adapter with same implementation. Here is my adapter,

```
class SelectedListDateAdapter(var listDate: List<DateDay>, private val onItemCheckListener: OnItemCheckListener) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectedListDateAdapter.SelectedListDateViewHolder>() {
lateinit var  binding: ItemCheckBoxDateBinding
inner class SelectedListDateViewHolder(item: ItemCheckBoxDateBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item.root) {
    val checkBoxList = item.checkBox
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SelectedListDateViewHolder {
    binding = ItemCheckBoxDateBinding.inflate(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
        parent,
        false
    )
    return SelectedListDateViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SelectedListDateViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.itemView.tvDateList.text = listDate[position].date
    holder.checkBoxList.isChecked = listDate[position].isSelected
    holder.checkBoxList.setOnClickListener {

        listDate[position].isSelected = holder.checkBoxList.isChecked
    }

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

        holder.checkBoxList.isChecked = !holder.checkBoxList.isChecked
        listDate[position].isSelected = holder.checkBoxList.isChecked

        val currentItem = listDate[position]
        if (holder.checkBoxList.isChecked) {
            onItemCheckListener.onItemCheck(currentItem.date)
        } else {
            onItemCheckListener.onItemUncheck(currentItem.date)
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return listDate.size
}
```

}

i think when im using the same adapter for different recyclerview it will reset the data
if it is possible how to do that ? if not should i make different adapter and layout ?

any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use different data for each adapter, the adapter behavior depends on the data you provide it, so if you provide the same data and you have two recyclerviews they both gonna display the same thing

Comment: did you mean data is List i provide in adapter parameter ?

Comment: i've try it, my problem still persist. do you need some additional information on my project ?

Comment: that would be helpful in order to assist you, maybe you can post some gif or screenshots displaying the issue cause to my understanding you are providing the same adapter with same data and expect different results

Comment: i expect my chekbox not checked if im not checking it, here's my problem https://ibb.co/wsSLFBR