# How can I select only one checkbox in Recyclerview and notifydataset changed

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

In my code I have create recyclerview with check box and default one item selected already. now I want when select other item checkbox so deselect all other items mean one item select at time.

My Adapter code:

```
public class SupportSchoolIdAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SupportSchoolIdAdapter.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<SupportSchoolIdModel> supportSchoolIdModels;
DataPref mDataPref;
String supportSchoolId;

public SupportSchoolIdAdapter(List<SupportSchoolIdModel> supportSchoolIdModels) {
    this.supportSchoolIdModels = new ArrayList<>(supportSchoolIdModels);
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    mDataPref = DataPref.getInstance(context);
    supportSchoolId = mDataPref.getSupportSchoolId();
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.support_school_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final SupportSchoolIdModel event = supportSchoolIdModels.get(position);
    holder.bindData(supportSchoolIdModels.get(position));

    //in some cases, it will prevent unwanted situations
    holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    //if true, your checkbox will be selected, else unselected
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(supportSchoolIdModels.get(position).isSelected());

    holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            supportSchoolIdModels.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setSelected(isChecked);
        }
    });
    if (supportSchoolIdModels.get(position).getPkSchoolId().equalsIgnoreCase(supportSchoolId)) {
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
    }
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return supportSchoolIdModels.size();
}
// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    private TextView schoolIdTxt;
    private TextView schoolNameTxt;
    private CheckBox checkbox;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        schoolIdTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.schoolIdTxt);
        schoolNameTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.schoolNameTxt);
        checkbox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    }
    public void bindData(SupportSchoolIdModel supportSchoolIdModel) {
        schoolIdTxt.setText(supportSchoolIdModel.getPkSchoolId());
        schoolNameTxt.setText(supportSchoolIdModel.getSchoolName());
    }
}
}
```

And Second problem is when I scroll recycle view why selected item unchecked. please help me.

Comment: Ok. You should first solve:  if the user checks one item and then scrolls the item out an in view that the checkbox is still checked. This problem bas been reported many times and there is a simple solution with the use of a boolean array. One boolean for every item. The boolean value indicates if the checkbox has to be checked. Google for code. Once you have mastered that the unchecking of other boxes is pretty simple.

Comment: no I mean why checkbox deselected. I don't want this @greenapps

Comment: Yes i understood. Thats exactly what i referred to.

Comment: I have found out a lot of solutions but I am failing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is the best code!
notice onBindViewHolder

```
public class SupportSchoolIdAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SupportSchoolIdAdapter.ViewHolder > {

private Context context;
ArrayList<SupportSchoolIdModel> supportSchoolIdModels;
private int selectedPosition = 0;
private ArrayList<Integer> selectCheck = new ArrayList<>();

public SupportSchoolIdAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<SupportSchoolIdModel> supportSchoolIdModels) {
    this.context = context;
    this.supportSchoolIdModels = supportSchoolIdModels;

//initilize selectCheck 
    for (int i = 0; i < supportSchoolIdModels.size(); i++) {
        selectCheck.add(0);
    }

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.support_school_item, parent, false);
     return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (selectCheck.get(position) == 1) {
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
    }

    holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int k=0; k<selectCheck.size(); k++) {
                if(k==position) {
                    selectCheck.set(k,1);
                } else {
                    selectCheck.set(k,0);
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
    holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked==true){
                //Do whatever you want to do with selected value
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return supportSchoolIdModels== null? 0: supportSchoolIdModels.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolde {

    CheckBox checkbox;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        checkbox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);          
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 26):

1- You can create a variable inside Adapter class that can be used to hold the selected position:

`private int selectedPosition = -1;// no selection by default`

2- Inside **onBindViewHolder** set Check State:

`holder.checkBox.setChecked(selectedPosition == position);`

3- Inside **setOnCheckedChangeListener** you must update position

`this.selectedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();`

4- Refresh adapter

`adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();`

***EDIT***

**onBindViewHolder** will be called for all positions,

So method **setChecked** will called for all CheckBoxes,
This method have a boolean input.

In above example i write `setChecked(selectedPosition == position)`. For more readable i can write:

```
if(selectedPosition == position){ 
   holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
}
else{
   holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
}
```

Comment: Ok. Simple but will only work if you call an adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() too.

Comment: Yes, sorry i missed one line

Comment: onBindViewHolder will be called for all positions. So method `setChecked` will called for all checkBoxes. This method have a boolean input. In above example i write setChecked(selectedPosition == position). For more readable i can write `if(selectedPosition == position){ setChecked(true)}else{ setChecked(false) }

Comment: They will be deselected automatically if you call notifyDatasetChanged(). That makes this a very nice solution.

Comment: in my code I have getting can not resolved this.selectedPosition variable where define

Comment: You will define it at level of your global variables ( so at level of  ArrayList<SupportSchoolIdModel> supportSchoolIdModels;
DataPref mDataPref;
String supportSchoolId;)

Comment: where I can define adapter.notifydatasetchanged();

Comment: still not solved  holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
             @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                this.selectedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            }
        });

Comment: Not define. but call. In `onCheckedChanged`. After `selectedPosition = position;` Or `selectedPositoio = -1` when user deselects.

Comment: there error selectedPosition (can not resolved variable)

Comment: For this  line( this.selectedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition(); ) selectedPosition  variable where define@an_droid_dev. I have define globle but still it can not be resolved

Comment: Remove the `this.`. And make it a private variable of your adapter class.

Comment: adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(); called inside Fragment or Activity not adapter

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code; it will surely help you guys,

```
int selectedPosition=0;

 if (selectedPosition == position) {
            holder.itemView.setSelected(true); //using selector drawable


            GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) holder.ll_portal.getBackground();
            drawable.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkorange));
            holder.tvPortalName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));


        } else {
            holder.itemView.setSelected(false);
            GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) holder.ll_portal.getBackground();
            drawable.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            holder.tvPortalName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }

        final int finalPosition = position;
        holder.ll_portal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                totalDineInOrder= String.valueOf(gallaryModels.get(position).getDineInTotalOrder());
                totalPickupOrder= String.valueOf(gallaryModels.get(position).getPickupTotalOrder());
                selectedPosition= finalPosition;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this, complete example**

```
public class ChildAddressAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChildAddressAdapter.CartViewHolder> {

    private Activity context;
    private List<AddressDetail> addressDetailList;
    private int selectedPosition = -1;

    public ChildAddressAdapter(Activity context, List<AddressDetail> addressDetailList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.addressDetailList = addressDetailList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.address_layout, parent, false);
        return new CartViewHolder(myView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.adress_checkbox.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            selectedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        });

        if (selectedPosition==position){
            holder.adress_checkbox.setChecked(true);
        }
        else {
            holder.adress_checkbox.setChecked(false);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  addressDetailList.size();
    }

    class CartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView address_text,address_tag;
        CheckBox adress_checkbox;

        CartViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            address_text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.address_text);
            address_tag = itemView.findViewById(R.id.address_tag);
            adress_checkbox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adress_checkbox);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you are new to android first you will notice that your checkbox will have issues with recycler view.You selected some item in recycle view and after scrolling you will notice some other item is selected to solve this you need to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499934/save-checkbox-state-in-recyclerview).
or
You need to create a boolean variable( to capture the state of checked checkbox for each item in recycler view)in your School Model class like this

```
 class SchoolModel{
    private boolean isChecked;
    public boolean isChecked(){
     return ischecked;}

    public void setIsChecked(boolean checked){
      isChecked = checked;
    }
   }
```

Second problem is to select only one checkbox and deselect rest of them for this you need write your logic([Check here for solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972049/single-selection-in-recyclerview)).And one major code change is to move your setOnCheckedChangeListener to view holder class because bindviewholder is called everytime you update your recyclerview and thus setting setOnCheckedChangeListener every time which is not correct.So you put this listener in view holder this will assign per checkbox listener only one time.

```
 checkBoxDeleteComment.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
               //your code
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

public class MyTeamAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList myTeams;

```
private int prevSelection = -1;


public MyTeamAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Team> myTeams) {
    this.context = context;
    this.myTeams = myTeams;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_my_team, parent, false));
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Team team = myTeams.get(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;

    if (team.isTeamSelected()) {
        viewHolder.checkTeam.setChecked(true);
        prevSelection = position;
    } else {
        viewHolder.checkTeam.setChecked(false);
    }

    viewHolder.checkTeam.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                team.setTeamSelected(true);
                if (prevSelection >= 0) {
                    myTeams.get(prevSelection).setTeamSelected(false);
                    notifyItemChanged(prevSelection);
                }
                prevSelection = position;
            } else {
                team.setTeamSelected(false);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return myTeams.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    RelativeLayout captainHolder, viceCaptainHolder;
    CheckBox checkTeam;
    TextView tvTeamName, tvCaptainName, tvCaptain, tvVCapName, tvVC, tvWcktKeeper, tvBatsMen, tvAllRounder, tvBowler;
    ImageView edtTeam, viewTeam, copyTeam;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        checkTeam = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_team);

        tvTeamName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_team_name);

        captainHolder = itemView.findViewById(R.id.captain_holder);
        tvCaptainName = captainHolder.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_name);
        tvCaptain = captainHolder.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_type);

        viceCaptainHolder = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vc_holder);
        tvVCapName = viceCaptainHolder.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_name);
        tvVC = viceCaptainHolder.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_type);

        tvWcktKeeper = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_wckt_keeper);
        tvBatsMen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_bats_men);
        tvAllRounder = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_all_rounder);
        tvBowler = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_baller);

        edtTeam = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edt_team);
        viewTeam = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_team);
        copyTeam = itemView.findViewById(R.id.copy_team);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: May be this would help.