# Having checkbox in listview,scrolling loses selected checkbox and random checkbox get checked

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-arrayadapter

Having checkbox in listview,scrolling loses selected checkbox and random checkbox get checked
Having checkbox in listview ,scrolling loses selected checkbox and
random checkbox get checked.
I am scrolling this listview selected checkbox is unchecked.
Checkbox loses their state

> ```
> public class FriendList extends ArrayAdapter<FriendListResult> {
>     private List<FriendListResult> list;
>     LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
>     public int resource;
>     private Holder holder = null;
>
>   //Constructor
>   public FriendList(Context context, int resource, List<FriendListResult> objects) {
>     super(context, resource, objects);
>     this.list = objects;
>     this.resource = resource;
>       // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
>     this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
>     }
>
> // getview method
> @Override
> public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
> // check if view is null or not
> // create new row view
>     if (view == null) {
> // inflating layout
>         view = layoutInflater.inflate(resource, null);
> // initializing  holder
>         holder = new Holder();
>         holder.txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvContactNameMain);
>      // checkbox defined
>         holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkboxFriendListItem);
>         view.setTag(holder);
>     } 
>     else {
>         holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
>     }
>     // set value from the list
>     final FriendListResult friendListResult = list.get(position);
>     // get and set name
>     holder.txtTitle.setText(friendListResult.getNickname());
>
> // checkbox changeListener
> holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new  >CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
> @Override
> public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
> //  Maximum three selection for checkbox
>   {   
>   if (checkArrayList.size() >= 3 && isChecked) {
>         buttonView.setChecked(false); 
> Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You have already chosen 3 friends",
>         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>     } else if (isChecked) {
>        //  storing position id to arraylist
>         checkArrayList.add(getItem(position).getId());
>         notifyDataSetChanged();
>       // userCheckCount to get the count
>         userCheckCount++;
>     } else if (!isChecked) {    
>     //removing position from arraylist
>         checkArrayList.remove(getItem(position).getId());
>         notifyDataSetChanged();
>         userCheckCount--;
>     }    
>   } 
>  });
>   return view;
> }
>  // holder class initializing widgets
>     class Holder {   
>     private TextView txtTitle;
>     private CheckBox checkBox;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: I recommend using [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) which provides default mechanism to deal with this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link.
Use POJO class to save the checked status of the checkbox.
Its simple just go through this link.

> http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/01/recyclerview-with-checkbox-example.html
>
> [CheckBox in RecyclerView keeps on checking different items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427889/checkbox-in-recyclerview-keeps-on-checking-different-items)