# recyclerview items get changed when i scroll recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-contacts

**multiple items get selected automatically when i select one item in recyclerview**

**What i m doing is**

> i just want to fetch contacts with no duplication and list all contacts in recyclerview And make visible two textviews (one is for number and second is for name)Its Done But The **problem is**
>
> **when i click on an item it gets clicked 4 times (for example if i click on an item it make visible two textviews but the same item with same name and number get visible like with i have clicked 4 items and  see pics  )**

**adpter class**

```
    package "";

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.altu.calllocker.R;
import com.example.altu.calllocker.model.ContactsModel;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class ContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsAdapter.ContactsViewHolder> {
    List<ContactsModel> list;
    Context context;
    public static HashMap<String, String> hashMapBlock;

    public ContactsAdapter(List<ContactsModel> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ContactsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contacts_item, parent, false);
        context = parent.getContext();
        hashMapBlock = new HashMap<>();
        ContactsViewHolder viewHolder = new ContactsViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ContactsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.txtno.setText(list.get(position).get_id());
        holder.txt_contactname.setText(list.get(position).getDisplay_name());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("position", list.get(position).get_id() + "  " + list.get(position).getData1() + "  " + list.get(position).getDisplay_name());
                if (holder.linearLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.txt_contactName.setText(list.get(position).getDisplay_name());
                    holder.txt_contact_no.setText(list.get(position).getData1());
                }

            }
        });
        holder.switchBlock.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    hashMapBlock.put(list.get(position).getData1(), "block");
                    Log.e("block", list.get(position).getData1());
                    Toast.makeText(context, "block" + "  " + list.get(position).getData1(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    hashMapBlock.remove(list.get(position).getData1());
                    Log.e("unblock", list.get(position).getData1());
                    Toast.makeText(context, "unblock" + "  " + list.get(position).getData1(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ContactsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txt_contactname;
        TextView txt_contactName;
        TextView txt_contact_no;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        SwitchCompat switchBlock;
        TextView txtno;

        public ContactsViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            this.txtno = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtno);
            this.txt_contactname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_contactName);
            this.txt_contactName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_contact_name);
            this.txt_contact_no = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_contact_no);
            this.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
            this.switchBlock = (SwitchCompat) itemView.findViewById(R.id.switchButton_block);


        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity where i get all contacts to recyclerview**

```
 package "";

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.altu.calllocker.R;
import com.example.altu.calllocker.adapter.ContactsAdapter;
import com.example.altu.calllocker.customclass.SimpleDividerItemDecoration;
import com.example.altu.calllocker.model.ContactsModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerview_contacts;
    List<ContactsModel> contactVOList;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bindview();
        new Thread(new Task()).start();
        progressDialog.dismiss();


        //adapter = new ContactsAdapter(contactlist, getApplicationContext());
        //recyclerview_contacts.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void bindview() {
        recyclerview_contacts = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_contacts);
        contactVOList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerview_contacts.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerview_contacts.setLayoutManager(llm);
        SimpleDividerItemDecoration itemDecoration = new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(this);
        recyclerview_contacts.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading.....");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    class Task implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getAllContact();
                }
            });


        }

    }



    private void getAllContact() {
        if (contactVOList.size() > 0) {
            contactVOList.clear();
        }
        //  List<ContactsModel> contactVOList = new ArrayList();
        ContactsModel contactVO;

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
                if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    contactVO = new ContactsModel();
                    contactVO.setDisplay_name(name);
                    contactVO.set_id(id);

                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id},
                            null);
                    if (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        contactVO.setData1(phoneNumber);
                    }

                    phoneCursor.close();

                    Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String emailId = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    }
                    emailCursor.close();
                    contactVOList.add(contactVO);
                }

            }

            ContactsAdapter contactAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(contactVOList, getApplicationContext());
            //recyclerview_contacts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerview_contacts.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
            contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.e("size", String.valueOf(contactVOList.size()));
        }
    }

}
```

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA7Hh.jpg) [image2 with auto selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2476n.jpg)

Comment: Check this:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427889/checkbox-in-recyclerview-keeps-on-checking-different-items)

Comment: try to hold the clicked state of that item and then notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @PavliukR it isn't related to my problem ...

Comment: @RushiAyyappa any a single line code hint?

Comment: maintain a boolean variable isClicked in model..after selecting an item arraylist.get(clickedposition).setisChecked=true; then call notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @RushiAyyappa check update question title its about to clicking not about selecting

Comment: the thing is in recyclerview all the item positions get zigzagged because onBind method keeps called all the time.hence to control this we should maintain the state of the selected items.now the answer i gave you will work for both item as wel row.. and you select an item by a click right?

Answer (score 1):

You should set `OnclickListener` inside `ViewHolder` and get clicked Item's posision with `getLayoutPosition()` method.

```
 public class ContactsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_contactname;
    TextView txt_contactName;
    TextView txt_contact_no;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    SwitchCompat switchBlock;
    TextView txtno;

    public ContactsViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        this.txtno = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtno);
        this.txt_contactname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_contactName);
        this.txt_contactName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_contact_name);
        this.txt_contact_no = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_contact_no);
        this.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
        this.switchBlock = (SwitchCompat) itemView.findViewById(R.id.switchButton_block);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 int position =getLayoutPosition();
                //Your logic

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: @beginner You should try to debug the ClickListener and see what actually is heppening