# Android RecyclerView checkbox checks itself

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which has a checkbox and textview.Numbers 10,20,30,40... till 500 should be shown in textview.The Checked checkboxes should add the numbers in the textview corresponding to the checkbox.For eg. if User checks the value 10 only, the textView would show 10. If user checks 20 as well, then
TextView would show 30 ( 20 +10).
If user uncheck 10 again, the TextView would show 20, and so on.When i click on checkbox some random checkbox is also checked.I tried one solution in stackoverflow. It did not work.I am stuck with this.Please help me..Here is my code:

RecyclerAdapter.java:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerHolder>
    {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new RecyclerHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_lyt,parent,false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerHolder holder, final int position) {
            holder.number.setText(Integer.toString((Integer) alldata.get(position)));
            final String text=holder.number.getText().toString();


            holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    Log.e("Checked","Checked");
                    if(checkeddata!=null)
                    {
                        if (checkeddata.size()==0)
                        {
                            checkeddata.add(text);

                        }
                        else {
                            if(checkeddata.contains(text))
                            {
                                checkeddata.remove(text);


                            }
                            else {
                                checkeddata.add(text);

                        }
                        }
                        Iterator iterator=checkeddata.iterator();
                        int sumnumber=0;
                        while (iterator.hasNext())
                        {
                            sumnumber= sumnumber+Integer.parseInt((String) iterator.next());
                        }
                        sum.setText(Integer.toString(sumnumber));
                    }


                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return alldata.size();
        }

        public class RecyclerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            TextView number;
            CheckBox checkBox;
            public RecyclerHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                number=itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
                checkBox=itemView.findViewById(R.id.check);


            }
        }
    }
    public void data()
    {
        int g=1;
        for(int i=10;i<=500;i++)
        {
            if((i/10)==g)
            {
                g=g+1;
                alldata.add(i);
            }

        }
    }
```

recycler_lyt.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:checked="false"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `TextView` in which you displaying sum is outside of `RecyclerView` or inside. if inside then which `TextView` you want to edit. Please clarify your question with picture or something.

Comment: Sorry i didnt mention.There is another textview below recyclerview.The sum is displayed there.

Comment: What is alldata? Does it contain a boolean field for the state of the checkbox?

Comment: [you can check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427889/checkbox-in-recyclerview-keeps-on-checking-different-items) I think this is your answer.

Comment: all data is the list of numbers from 10 to 500 in this order..10..20..30..

Comment: [you can check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427889/checkbox-in-recyclerview-keeps-on-checking-different-items) I think this is your answer.

Comment: ^^^^ This question is indeed a duplicate of that post

Answer (score 3):

It's normal. You are not setting your checkbox selected or not. You are selecting one and View holder keeps it selected

You may look at my example. You can do something like that:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Data data = myItems.get(position);

        //in some cases, it will prevent unwanted situations
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        //if true, your checkbox will be selected, else unselected
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(data.isSelected());

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    //set your object's last status
                    data.setSelected(isChecked);
            }
        });

    }
```

inside your `onBindViewHolder` you have to set your checkbox either checked or unchecked.
if true, your checkbox will be selected, else unselected

```
holder.checkBox.setChecked(boolean);
```

Answer (score 2):

You must store your checkbox state. You can do that in your model, for example:

```
class Model {
    String title;
    boolean checked;
}
```

Next you must pass `List` of `Model` items to your adapter and check/uncheck checkbox determined by your model.

```
if (listOfItems.get(position).checked) {
    viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
} else {
    viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
}
```

Remember that you always need to manage opposite state of views (like checkbox or visibility of view) in adapter.

Comment: Will let u know after i try that

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerHolder>
{
private OnClickListener onClickListener;
private int sum =0;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new RecyclerHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_lyt,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.number.setText(Integer.toString((Integer) alldata.get(position)));
        final String text=holder.number.getText().toString();


        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    sum += Integer.parseInt(holder.number.getText().toString());
                }else{
                    sum -= Integer.parseInt(holder.number.getText().toString());
                }
                if (onClickListener != null) {
                    onClickListener.onItemClick(sum);
                }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return alldata.size();
    }

    public class RecyclerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView number;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        public RecyclerHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            number=itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
            checkBox=itemView.findViewById(R.id.check);


        }
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
    }

    public interface OnClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int sum);
    }
}
```

Now In activity use `adapter` instance like this:

```
private RecyclerAdapter adapter;
...
...
cardAdapter.setOnClickListener(new CardAdapter.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int sum) {
            txtSum.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a field (like "isSelected") in your model class so that all the checked entries can be tracked.you can try following:

[checkboxRecyclerView](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-handling-checkbox-state-in-recycler-views-71b03f237022)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, RecyclerView recycles the view so you need a model to store the state of the checkbox.

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerHolder> {

    private List<Model> alldata = new ArrayList<>();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new RecyclerHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_lyt, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Model model = alldata.get(position);

        holder.number.setText(String.valueOf(model.value));
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                model.setChecked(isChecked); // Saves the state of the checkbox.

                if (checkeddata != null) {
                    if (checkeddata.size() == 0) {
                        checkeddata.add(text);

                    } else {
                        if (checkeddata.contains(model.getValue())) {
                            checkeddata.remove(model.getValue());


                        } else {
                            checkeddata.add(model.getValue());

                        }
                    }
                    Iterator iterator = checkeddata.iterator();
                    int sumnumber = 0;
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        sumnumber = sumnumber + Integer.parseInt((String) iterator.next());
                    }
                    sum.setText(Integer.toString(sumnumber));
                }
            }
        });
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(model.isChecked()); // Retrieves the state of your checkbox.
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return alldata.size();
    }

    public class RecyclerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView number;
        CheckBox checkBox;

        public RecyclerHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.check);
        }
    }

    public void data() {
        int g = 1;
        for (int i = 10; i <= 500; i++) {
            if ((i / 10) == g) {
                g = g + 1;
                alldata.add(new Model(i));
            }
        }
    }

    private class Model {
        private int value;
        private boolean checked = false;

        Model(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public boolean isChecked() {
            return checked;
        }

        public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
            this.checked = checked;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you made the necessary changes to store the state of the checkbox, then:  
in `onBindViewHolder()` after `final String text=holder.number.getText().toString();` add this:

```
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
holder.checkBox.setChecked(-- stored value --);
```

and then add the listener for the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

If your recyclerview checkBox changing it's value automatically then you should try this inside your recyclerview adapter class,

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```