# Android - How to keep the checked state of multiple checkboxes even if a user relaunches the app?

Tags: java, android, android-checkbox

I'm working on Android sdk platform. Working of app - A user selects multiple checkboxes and then on the basis of selection, the user would receive notifications. When a user relaunches the app, the selected checkboxes stay checked. What should be my approach? The below code is for one checkbox. I want to perform it for multiple checkboxes. How do I approach this?

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.arham.csdevbin.downloadimagefrominternet.SharedPreferencesDemo">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="103dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="103dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
        android:text="CheckBox" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
 CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    CheckBox checkBox;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shared_preferences);
        checkBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            checkBox.setText("The CheckBox is Checked");
        } else {
            checkBox.setText("The CheckBox is not Checked");
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onPause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("CHECK_BOX_VALUE", checkBox.getText().toString());
        editor.putBoolean("CH", checkBox.isChecked());
        editor.commit();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onResume", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(0);
        boolean checkBoxValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CH", false);
        String chBoxString = sharedPreferences.getString("CHECK_BOX_VALUE", "This is my CheckBox");
        checkBox.setChecked(checkBoxValue);
        checkBox.setText(chBoxString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to save value inside SharedPreference inside `onCheckedChanged` method instaed of using it in `onPause`

Comment: The above code has worked for one checkbox. I want it for multiple checkboxes.

Comment: Have you tried adding more checkboxes?

Comment: The above code will _not_ work if the user directly swipes out the app of recent apps. @S.Ambika is right - save the preference of each checkbox directly in the ``onCheckedChanged`` when the checkbox changes. works always.

Comment: Multiple Checkboxes as individual or inside recycler View?

Comment: I tried to do it for multiple checkboxes. Result - Successive checkboxes retaining value of first checkbox. T

Comment: May be something like this can help you <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427889/checkbox-in-recyclerview-keeps-on-checking-different-items>

Comment: I tried other methods too. It's not working at all. I'm new to android programming. Wish I could post screenshot of my app. Since Android has concept of sharedprefernces, why should we choose a complicated approach?

Comment: are you using multiple checkbox inside recyclerview items  or just use in normal view?

Comment: multiple checkbox - normal view

Comment: _"What should be my approach?"_ Follow [the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage). And SharedPreferences supports collections of simple data with the `Editor.putStringSet()` and `getStringSet()` methods. You just need to save the CheckBox states as strings. Could be "0" and "1" or "false" and "true". Whatever works conveniently.

Comment: Well show complete code for three ceckboxes for example. All this talking... we dont know what you tried.

Comment: If you have checkBox1, checkBox2 and checkBox3 then what is the problem of saving three states to shared preferences? But first try to let it work for one.

Comment: I tried above code for two checkboxes.

Comment: 1stCheckbox - Animal Sciences, 2nd checkbox - Fisheries. Result - 2nd checkbox retains the value of 1st checkbox

Comment: Instead of Fisheries, it shows Animal Sciences. Now there are duplicate values of Animal Sciences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `SharedPreference` and saved only one checkbox value. If you want to save multiple checkbox value you must store all selected checkbox values on `SharedPreference`.
I suggest you to save multiple values, use `HashMap` to get and set checkboxes in `SharedPreference`.

```
SharedPreferences preferences;
public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

public void setCheckboxes(HashMap<String, boolean> checkboxes) {

    editor.putString("checkbox_1", checkboxes.get("checkbox_1"));
    editor.putString("checkbox_2", checkboxes.get("checkbox_2"));
    editor.putString("checkbox_3", checkboxes.get("checkbox_3"));
    editor.putString("checkbox_4", checkboxes.get("checkbox_4"));
    editor.apply();
}

public HashMap<String, boolean> getCheckboxes() {
    HashMap<String, boolean> checkboxes = new HashMap<String, boolean>();
    checkboxes.put("checkbox_1", preferences.getString("checkbox_1", false));
    checkboxes.put("checkbox_2", preferences.getString("checkbox_2", false));
    checkboxes.put("checkbox_3", preferences.getString("checkbox_3", false));
    checkboxes.put("checkbox_4", preferences.getString("checkbox_4", false));

return checkboxes;

}
```

Comment: For put() and get() and boolean, what libraries do I use since they are showing errors?

Comment: did you import `HashMap` library?