# Cannot change item data inside currentList of ListAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox, android-listadapter

I'm trying to create a RecyclerView that having checkbox in each of its item. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427889/checkbox-in-recyclerview-keeps-on-checking-different-items) to save states of checkbox, that is to add a boolean variable to my object. However, I encountered a problem that the value of `isChecked` from my object cannot be changed. Is the content of `currentList` immutable? Is there any way for me to implement this feature with ListAdapter?

Here is the snippet of my code. Thank you very much.

```
class DocumentAdapter() : ListAdapter<Document, DocumentAdapter.DocumentViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DocumentViewHolder {
        return LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_document, parent, false)
            .let {
                DocumentViewHolder(it)
            }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VH, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }

    class DocumentViewHolder(
        override val view: View
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder<DocumentDTO>(view) {

        fun bind(item: Document) {
            cbItem.isChecked = item.isChecked
            cbItem.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                item.isChecked = isChecked // Not working
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When debugging, after running through the line `item.isChecked = isChecked`, I can see value `isChecked` inside `currentList` is not updated, even though that value of the local `Document` item has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since mutation to content of ListAdapter must be submitted through submitList(), I have to create a callback and send the updated item out to update the data.

```
    fun bind(item: Document) {
        cbItem.isChecked = item.isChecked
        cbItem.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            item.isChecked = isChecked
            onCheckBoxClicked(item, isChecked)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that the content of a ListAdapter is immutable, it's that, from what I see in your code snippet, that the `Document`'s isChecked variable is immutable.

The `Document` object itself should be able to hold stateful data of the current item that needs to be displayed. If you are not able to tweak the `Document` object itself, I would either create a `DocumentWrapper` object that allows you to create an initial and mutable checked state.

```
class DocWrapper(val document: Document) {
  var isChecked = document.isChecked
}
```

You can map your data before submitting to your ListAdapter

```
val docList = List<Document>()
val docWrapperList: List<DocWrapper> = docList.map { DocWrapper(it) }
```

Comment: Hi, I'm pretty sure I have set `isChecked` as `var`. However, when debugging, after running through the line `item.isChecked = isChecked`, I can see value `isChecked` inside currentList is not updated. Even though the local `Document` item has been updated. Do you have any thoughts about this?