# How to work with checkboxes using recyclerview kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am trying to:

**Get selected checked checkbox item in my fragment**

**What I have Tried**

So, as I know there are 2 ways of saving state of checked box while scrolling in recyclerview

- Using SparseBooleanArray ()
- Using your model to save the state

I went for option 1.

**Model - Songs.kt**

```
data class Songs(
val songId: Int? = null,
)
```

**Adapter - SelectSongAdapter.kt**

```
//In OnBindViewHolder - 
binding.checkbox.isChecked = checkBoxStateArray.get(position, 
false)

//function to get all checked songs
 fun getSelectedIds(): SparseBooleanArray {
    return checkBoxStateArray
}

 //In adapter viewHolder
checkbox.setOnClickListener {
if (!checkBoxStateArray.get(bindingAdapterPosition, false)).  
{//checkbox checked
checkbox.isChecked = true
//stores checkbox states and position
checkBoxStateArray.put(bindingAdapterPosition, true)
} else {//checkbox unchecked
checkbox.isChecked = false
//stores checkbox states and position.
checkBoxStateArray.put(bindingAdapterPosition, false)
 }
}
```

**Fragment - SelectSongFragment.kt**

```
 //get selected items - this returns an empty list, even when some 
 items are checked
 
 val selectedRows = selectSongsAdapter.getSelectedIds()
 Log.e("selectedSongs", selectedRows.toString())
```

**QUESTION**

How to get the selected items from adapter to fragment.
My code is returning an empty list.

I want to get any checked/selected item from the adapter to my fragment (observing changes)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `setOnClickListener`  on `CheckBox`'s, instead you need to use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` which has `isChecked` callback parameter.

Also, don't set `CheckBox` value programmatically within the adapter as this should be triggered by the user

So replace:

```
checkbox.setOnClickListener {
    if (!checkBoxStateArray.get(bindingAdapterPosition, false)).{//checkbox checked
        checkbox.isChecked = true
        //stores checkbox states and position
        checkBoxStateArray.put(bindingAdapterPosition, true)
    } else {//checkbox unchecked
        checkbox.isChecked = false
        //stores checkbox states and position.
        checkBoxStateArray.put(bindingAdapterPosition, false)
}
```

With:

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
    checkBoxStateArray.put(bindingAdapterPosition, isChecked)
})
```

Comment: Hello. I read from a comment that its not safe using onCheckedChangeListner.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41843879/15985008

I have replaced but my issue remains: Getting selected item in my fragment

Answer (score 0):

- Pass a call back function in your constructor of the adapter class
  itemCheckListener: (isChecked: Boolean, data: MutableList) -> Unit
- get data if isChecked is true

// make it global and you can use any class instead of the string class

```
 private val data = mutableListOf<String>()

 holder.binding.isChecked.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            data.add(getItemPosition)
            itemCheckListener(isChecked, data)
        }
```

- Using it in your in your fragment

//get data

```
val myAdapter: MyAdapterClass by lazy {
                MyAdapterClass { isActive, data->
                    Log.d("CLICKS", "YOU CLICK  FRAGMENT $data")}
            }
```