# Check box in recycleView android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to implement recycle view with checkbox when I checked one checkbox it selecting two checkbox at a time.
I have tried some option as well but no luck help me to resolve the problem.
**CheckBox** is not working properly when I tried to select any item from the list Its selecting the two item from the list and when I un check the checkBox both are unchecked.

```
    public class RecyclerViewAdapterDc extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterDc.ViewHolderDc> {
    Context context;
//    public ArrayList<String> checkBoxArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<DCModelClass> dcModelClassList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<AllProductsOfBag> allProductsOfBagsList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<AllProductsofBagDcDeliver> allProductsofBagDcDeliverList = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<AllProductsofBagDcDeliver> checkedallProductsofBagDcDeliverList = new ArrayList<>();
    GlobalData globalData = new GlobalData();
//    private final boolean mCheckStates[];
    private ArrayList<Integer> selectCheck = new ArrayList<>();



    public RecyclerViewAdapterDc(Context context, List<DCModelClass> dcModelClassList,
                                 List<AllProductsofBagDcDeliver> allProductsofBagDcDeliverList) {
//        List<AllProductsOfBag> allProductsOfBagsList
        this.context = context;
        this.dcModelClassList = dcModelClassList;
//        this.allProductsOfBagsList = allProductsOfBagsList;
        this.allProductsofBagDcDeliverList = allProductsofBagDcDeliverList;
//        mCheckStates = new boolean[allProductsofBagDcDeliverList.size()];
    }

    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolderDc onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout_dc_home, parent, false);
        ViewHolderDc viewHolderDc = new ViewHolderDc(view);

        return viewHolderDc;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewHolderDc holder, int position) {
//        holder.bindProduct(allProductsofBagDcDeliverList.get(position));

//        if (dcModelClassList.size() > 0) {
//            holder.bagNumber.setText(String.valueOf(dcModelClassList.get(position).getBaG_ID_NUMBER()));

        //today
        holder.waybill.setText(allProductsofBagDcDeliverList.get(position).getProducT_WAYBILL_NUMBER());
        holder.ConsingeeName.setText(allProductsofBagDcDeliverList.get(position).getConsigneE_NAME());
        holder.orderID.setText(allProductsofBagDcDeliverList.get(position).getReferencE_NO());
        //todayend

//            holder.shortAddress.setText(allProductsofBagDcDeliverList.get(position).get());

        //today
        if (allProductsofBagDcDeliverList.get(position).getProducT_PAYMENT_TYPE().contains("COD")) {
            holder.ppOrCod.setText(String.valueOf(allProductsofBagDcDeliverList.get(position).getProducT_VALUE_AMOUNT()));
        } else {
            holder.ppOrCod.setText(allProductsofBagDcDeliverList.get(position).getProducT_PAYMENT_TYPE());
        }

        holder.shortAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openPopUpDialog(position);
            }

            private void openPopUpDialog(int position) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                builder.setTitle(" Full Address of Client")
                        .setMessage(allProductsofBagDcDeliverList.get(position).getAddress())
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        });
                builder.create();
                builder.show();
            }
        });
        //todayend



        holder.setItemSelectedListner(new IsSelectedClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onIsSelectedClick(View view, int position) {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) view;
                if (chk.isChecked()){
                    checkedallProductsofBagDcDeliverList.add(allProductsofBagDcDeliverList.get(position));
                }else if(!chk.isChecked()){
                    checkedallProductsofBagDcDeliverList.remove(allProductsofBagDcDeliverList.get(position));
                }
            }
        });







//        holder.checkBox.setTag(position);
////        holder.chkSelect.setTag(position);
////        holder.checkBox.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
////        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
//
//        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//
//                if (holder.checkBox.isChecked() == true) {
//                    checkBoxArrayList.add(allProductsofBagDcDeliverList.get(position).getProducT_WAYBILL_NUMBER());
//                    globalData.setWaybill(checkBoxArrayList);
//                    holder.constraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66bb6a"));
//
//
//
//                    //Log.d("GlobalData", globalData.getWaybill().toString());
//                } else {
//                    // holder.assign.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                    checkBoxArrayList.remove(allProductsofBagDcDeliverList.get(position).getProducT_WAYBILL_NUMBER());
////                        globalData.setWaybill(checkBoxArrayList);
//                    holder.constraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
//
//                }
//            }
//        });




    }

//    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return allProductsofBagDcDeliverList.size();
    }

    public void filterList(List<AllProductsofBagDcDeliver> filteredList) {

        allProductsofBagDcDeliverList = filteredList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }






    public class ViewHolderDc extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView waybill, ConsingeeName, orderID, shortAddress, ppOrCod, bagNumber;
        ImageButton clientPhoneButton;
        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        Button assign;
        IsSelectedClickListener isSelectedClickListener;

        public ViewHolderDc(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
//            bagNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idBagNumberDc);
            waybill = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idWaybill);
            ConsingeeName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idName);
            orderID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idOrderid);
            shortAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idShortAddress);
            ppOrCod = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idPaymentType);
//            clientPhoneButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idImageButtonCall);
            constraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idConstrainLayoutCustomLayoutDc);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idCheckBoxDc);
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);


        }

        public void setItemSelectedListner(IsSelectedClickListener ic){

            this.isSelectedClickListener = ic;
        }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            this.isSelectedClickListener.onIsSelectedClick(v,getLayoutPosition());

        }
    }

        public interface IsSelectedClickListener {

        void onIsSelectedClick(View view,int position);

    }
}
```

Comment: Try to move all the click listeners from onBindViewHolder to the ViewHolder constructor

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427889/checkbox-in-recyclerview-keeps-on-checking-different-items

Comment: Thank you for your help. Its already done. @YohannesMasterous